# Assigning group permissions in Flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-security

I have a Flask app that uses Flask-Security and MySQL. Unfortunately, Flask-Security does not provide group/multi-tenant management (https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/285).

I would like to implement the following:

1. At login the user enters his/her login credentials.
2. The user DB is inquired to see how many groups the user belongs to (Management, Accounting, Sales, etc.).
3. If the user belongs to more than one group, a pop up appears, listing the groups the user belongs to.
4. Upon selecting a group, the user is logged in, and a global variable (tenant_id or group_id) is set for the user's session. This global variable can then be used to pre-filter any DB searches by the user.

I'm not sure how to implement steps 2 and 4. Could one use the Flask g.object (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g) for implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Flask is a great framework and has many ready-to-use extensions but often requires some elbow grease when it comes to custom solutions.

Since this seems to be a feature that is missing from the authentication back end you are using there are some things you could consider:

- Switch to a back end that does include group management
- Roll your own
- Extend the current back end

the latter 2 options are both labor intensive.

Once you have the group management in place you can indeed use the flask g option. It should suffice to store a reference to the user object in it. Any querying and filtering van be done in the back end.

Some interesting reads:

[Building your own simple permission system](https://julo.ch/blog/sqlalchemy-many-to-many/) Might get you started if you decide to roll your own.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313492/python-group-user-management-packages) solution implements Flask-Principal

Answer (score 0):

You can most probably reuse Flask-Security's roles to do the user grouping and still keep it relevant to your use case.

You can do specific things based on what roles the users have and when they're in multiple roles, you can store a specific role in a session variable to keep track of which one they're in right now and show them the functions specific to that role(group).

```
if user_datastore.find_role("db_amin") in current_user.roles:
    ... db admin specific ...
```

You can also do role specific routes with decorators:

```
@roles_accepted("db_admin", "db_backup")
@roles_required('db_admin')
```

Documentation is at https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I currently use Flask-Security roles to separate out common roles within a group. For example, within each group I designate an admin role, secretary role, manager role, etc. What I'm looking for is a global group identifier that would apply to all members of the group/company. For a definition of a group please see my link in the question.